# How to get changing item's ids in jstree change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, jstree

I want to know which items checked or unchecked when it's changed.

```
var MenuTree = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Menu_Permission.aspx/Menu",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var menujson = JSON.parse(data.d);
            $('#tree_menu').jstree({
                'plugins': ["wholerow", "checkbox", "types"],
                'core': {
                    "themes": {
                        "responsive": false
                    },
                    'data': menujson
                }
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('err')
        }
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#tree_menu').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
            console.log(data.node);
            console.log(data.selected);
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#tree_menu').on('deselect_node.jstree Event', function (e, data) {
            console.log(data.node.id);
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('#tree_menu').on('select_node.jstree Event', function (e, data) {
            console.log(data.node.id);
        });
    });


}
```

I have these functions and `changed.jstree` returns object and I cannot reach the id which is clicked. Others return me id exactly but, if it is the last checked item and it changes, How will I know parents checkbox is changed or not. Otherwise if it is the root item and it has children, all of them will gone and how can I know it.
 `data.selected` returns me array of selected but is there any way to know which is changed, from slected to to unselected or reverse?

And the functions fire onload, how can I change it?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or jsbin with a specific example of what you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Use following:

```
$(function () {
    $('#tree_menu').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
        console.log(data.node.id);
    });
});
```

Instead of

```
console.log(data.node);
```

Use

```
console.log(data.node.id);
```